# Determine null, extreme and inflection points of function $f(x)=\frac{x+e^x}{x-e^x}$

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

This function has a null point, but I can't compute it from equation $f(x)=0$ which gives $$\frac{x+e^x}{x-e^x}=0$$ $$x+e^x=0$$ How to compute this equation?

Extreme points can be computed from equation $f'(x)=0$, $$\frac{(2x-2)e^x}{e^{2x}-2xe^x+x^2}=0$$ which gives $$L_{min}(1,-2.16)$$ is the only extreme point of $f(x)$.

Inflection points can't be computed from equation $f''(x)=0$ which gives 
$$-\frac{(2x-4)e^{2x}+(2x^2-4x+4)e^x}{e^{3x}-3xe^{2x}+3x^2e^{2x}-x^3}=0$$
Could someone show how to find inflection points of $f(x)$?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Do you need exact solutions in closed form, or are numeric approximations sufficient? The solution of $x+e^x=0$ is $-\operatorname{W}(1)\approx -0.567143$, where $\operatorname{W}(x)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Do you need the step-by-step solution of this?

Comment: @Rory Daulton  I would like to see step by step solutions. I tried using natural log, but can't figure it out.

Comment: for inflection: $f''(0)=0$

Comment: @no_name :\begin{align}x + e^x = 0 &\Leftrightarrow xe^{-x} = -1 \\ &\Leftrightarrow -x e^{-x} = 1 \\&\Leftrightarrow x = - W(1)\end{align}

Comment: @Joelafrite  Is there some more simple way because I don't know Lambert W function?

Comment: @no_name The Lambert $W$ function is the inverse function of $f(x) = x e^x$. There is no more simple way.

Comment: @Joelafrite  How to compute value for $W(1)$?

Comment: @no_name Let $(w_n)_n$ defined by : $$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l} w_0 = 1\\w_{n+1} = e^{-w_n}\end{array}\right.$$ One has : $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} w_n = W(1)$$

Comment: The inflection point can be guessed: $x=0$ Try it.

Comment: @zoli Is that the only intesection point?

Comment: @no_name: You mean: the inflection point... No, unfortunately there is another one around $2$. If you sketch the function you will see it. (Sorry.)

Comment: @zoli Do you know how to compute inflection point that is around $2$?

Comment: @no_name: I can only approx it. BTW it is around $3/2$ already. :)

Comment: [1]:http://zgyorfi.weebly.com/uploads/4/5/7/3/45737565/inflection.png